# Check if int is a power of 2 and return it

Tags: java

I have this program of Game of Nim where 2 players take turns removing marbles from a pile. Each player must remove 1 but no more than half of remaining marbles in the pile.

There are 3 type of players: Human, Dumb Computer, and Smart Computer.

I'm having trouble with the smart computer class. The smart computer is supposed to remove exactly enough marbles to make the remaining pile size a power of two minus one. (1, 3, 7, 15).

I need help on how to check if int that smart computer wants to remove is a power of 2.

Here is my SmartComputer class that implements Player interface

```
/**
 * Implements interface player Returns amount of marbles taken from pile and
 * players name
 */
class SmartComputer implements Player {

    /**
     * @param marbles receives amount of marbles in pile
     * @return number of marbles to remove from pile
     */
    public int move(int marbles) {
        int remove;
        int power = 2;
        //int div;
        //boolean check;

        //if marbles is less than 3 then just return 1
        if (marbles > 3) {

            while (power < marbles) {
                 power = power * 2;
            }

            power /= 2;

            remove = power - 1;

            return remove;
        }
        return 1; // temporary
    }

    public String playerName(String name) {
         return "Smart Computer"; //temporary
    }
}
```

Comment: step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Are you saying your code works but you want us to explain why it works?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I've seen examples but I haven't been able to make my program work.

Comment: @Straightup0 honestly it's hard to understand what you want us to do for you. If you're just looking for a "check if a number is power of 2" then it's enough to apply a conditional check on module of 2.  On the other hand, I think nobody's here to do your homework

Comment: What do you mean by conditional check on module of 2? @Con

Answer (score 1):

To find how many marbles we need to subtract, we need to find the largest (2^n-1) that is less than the number of marbles. Observe that one less than a power of 2 has all "1"s as the binary presentation, and powers of 2 have a single "1" in their binary representations.

- 1 is 1 in binary, 2 is 10 in binary
- 3 is 11 in binary, 4 is 100 in binary
- 7 is 111 in binary, 8 is 1000 in binary
- 15 is 1111 in binary, 16 is 10000 in binary
- 31 is 11111 in binary, 32 is 100000 in binary

So to do this, we first find the position of the most significant "1" bit, and calculate 2 to the power of that position using a bit shift. This gives the largest power of 2 that is less than or equal to `marble`.

```
int positionOfHighestOne = Integer.highestOneBit(marbles) - 1;
int nearestPowerOf2 = 1 << positionOfHighestOne;
```

Now we can easily get one less than that by subtracting:

```
int nearestOneLessThanPowerOf2 = nearestPowerOf2 - 1;
int marblesToSubtract = marbles - nearestOneLessThanPowerOf2;
return marblesToSubtract;
```